# kendo grid frozen columns kendo data binder is not working when using a template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, frozen-columns

I have a kendo grid with following structure ;

```
<div id="kendoGrid" data-role="grid" data-bind="source: search" data-scrollable="true" data-auto-bind="false" data-pageable="true" data-columns="[
{ title: '' , width: '100px',locked:true,  attributes: { style: 'overflow: visible' } , template: kendo.template($('#tamplate').html())},
{ field: 'name' , title: 'Name Surname' , width: 200},
{ field: 'date' , title: 'Date' , width: 150 },
{ field: 'residence' ,title: 'Residence' , width: 100 },
{ field: 'approveDate' ,title: 'Approve Date' , width: 200 },

</div>
```

I am also using a template to customize the data in first column. Here is my template;

```
<script id="tamplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
<span data-bind="text: nationality, tooltip: nationality"></span>
</script>
```

The problem is I am using kendo.data.binder and I have some extended methods such as "**tooltip**" but when I lock the column, it doesnt work The binder method doesnt get fired. Otherwise it works fine. It might seem easy to use **#= nationality #** format but I have much more complicated extended methods and I need them up and running. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Locked (frozen) columns are rendered in a different container and a [separate table](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-lockedTable). Take this into account when using `kendo.bind()` or any other logic that relies on DOM element structure.

Comment: Tnx for the reply, I have found that out. After a long search, I found out that the version I am using,  2014.1.528 , is not applying data-bind, I dont know why. But when I switch to version 2016.3.1118, it works fine. here is the dojos ;

2016.3.1118 -> http://dojo.telerik.com/OcuBe
2014.1.528 -> http://dojo.telerik.com/EDUbo

at the moment, we are unable to upgrade to version 2016 so it will remain like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I found out that the version I am using, 2014.1.528 , is not applying data-bind, I dont know why. But when I switch to version 2016.3.1118, it work fine. here is the dojos ;

2016.3.1118 -> [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EDUbo)
2014.1.528 -> [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EDUbo)

at the moment, we are unable to upgrade to version 2016 so it will remain like this.